# How to do nested foreach loops in smarty templating engine?

Tags: php, smarty, templating, smarty3, smarty2

I am new to smarty and trying to implement a nested foreach loop. So I have two tables subCategory and members where members and subCategory can be joined by subcategory_id. There are around for example, 5 categories and around 50 members belonging to any of these 5 categories. I want to loop the sub categories first and then show the members under each category. But I am not being able to do the second foreach in smarty. In normal php I am able to do but not in smarty. Please help.

php code

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM subCategory ");
$list_subchannels = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
{

        $subcategory = $row['subcat_id'];
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM member JOIN subCategory ON member.subcategory_id = subCategory.subcat_id WHERE member.subcategory_id = '$subcategory' ");
        $list_subchannels = array();
        while ( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1) )
        {
            $list_subchannels[] = $row1;
            $smarty->assign($row1['subcat_name'],$list_subchannels);

        }


        $list_subcategories[] = $row;
        $smarty->assign("subcategory",$list_subcategories);

}
```

The .tpl code is

```
{foreach from=$subcategory key=k item=b}
    Sub Category Names: {$b.subcat_name}

    <!-- Listing Item -->
    {foreach from=$b.subcat_name key=k item=a}
                    <h3>Member Name: {$a.channel_name}</h3>
                    <span>Member Id: {$a.member_id}</span>
    {/foreach}                
    <!-- Listing Item / End -->

{/foreach}
```

It is correctly displaying all the sub category names (i.e the first foreach) but displaying the members under them. TIA

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM subCategory ");
$list_subchannels = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    $subcategory = $row['subcat_id'];
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM member JOIN subCategory ON member.subcategory_id = subCategory.subcat_id WHERE member.subcategory_id = '$subcategory' ");
    $list_subchannels = array();
    while ( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1) )
    {
        // $list_subchannels[] = $row1; // COMMENT
        // $smarty->assign($row1['subcat_name'],$list_subchannels); // COMMENT

        $list_subchannels[$subcategory] = $row1; // HERE
    }

    $list_subcategories[] = $row;
    $smarty->assign("subcategory",$list_subcategories);
    $smarty->assign("subchannels", $list_subchannels); // HERE
}
```

TPL Code:

```
{foreach from=$subcategory key=k item=b}
    Sub Category Names: {$b.subcat_name}

    <!-- Listing Item -->
    {foreach from=$subchannels[$b.subcat_id] key=k item=a} // HERE
                <h3>Member Name: {$a.channel_name}</h3>
                <span>Member Id: {$a.member_id}</span>
    {/foreach}                
    <!-- Listing Item / End -->

{/foreach}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using {function} {/function}.

For example:

```
{function name=subcategory_listing level=0}
    {foreach $subcategory as $subc}
        {if $level == 0}
            Sub Category Names: {$subc.subcat_name}
        {else}
            <h3>Member Name: {$subc.channel_name}</h3>
            <span>Member Id: {$subc.member_id}</span>
        {/if}

        {subcategory_listing cats=$subc.subcat_name level=$level+1}
    {/foreach}
 {/function}

 {subcategory_listing cats=$subcategory}
```